# aria.touch.swipeend event issue--not working as expected

Tags: ariatemplates

I am trying to use swipe events to obtain iphone like toggle switch. i want to handle swipemove and swipeend events. For example:

```
<div class="xyz" {on swipemove {fn:"swipemoveHandler"} /}> </div>
```

is working as expected while,

```
 <div class="xyz" {on swipeend {fn:"swipeendHandler"} /}> </div>
```

is throwing error "The event type: 'swipeend' is an invalid event type."

I am using AT1.3.7 and any help in this regard is greatly helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'swipe' event of Aria templates which is triggered after a swipe is completed.
Please refer to sample below. This was included in AT 1.3.4

```
    swipeHandler : function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(true);
        document.getElementById("touchMe").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("swipeDirection").innerHTML = event.direction;
        document.getElementById("swipeDistance").innerHTML = event.distance;
        document.getElementById("swipeLength").innerHTML = event.duration;
        document.getElementById("swipeStartX").innerHTML = event.startX;
        document.getElementById("swipeStartY").innerHTML = event.startY;
        document.getElementById("swipeEndX").innerHTML = event.endX;
        document.getElementById("swipeEndY").innerHTML = event.endY;
        return false;
    }
```

Below you can see how event can be attached to an element

```
<div id="touchboard"
  {on swipe {
    fn : this.swipeHandler,
    scope : this
  }/}
>
  <!-- your content -->
</div>
```

Refer to link for more help http://snippets.ariatemplates.com/samples/github.com/ariatemplates/documentation-code/samples/utils/touch/swipe/

Comment: i saw this snippet. However, I am unable to detect precisely "swipeend" event.